# Regex - Checks a letter repeating at least twice

Tags: regex

I want to check whether a string includes the letter `a` (lowercase or uppercase) at least twice. I wrote the regex pattern and checked its working on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/).

`[aA]+[^aA]*[aA]+`

Sample strings to match:

```
banana   #True
pineapple  #False
Animal Kingdom  #True
A is for apple  #True
```

Though the code is working as expected, I am concerned about whether there are better ways to get it done, or are there some cases that aren't going to match with my regex.

Comment: Why does `pineapple` match? How about `.*([Aa].*){2}`?

Comment: Your regex is almost perfect. You do not need `+`s, `[aA][^aA]*[aA]` will do

Comment: re.search(r"[aA].*[aA].*", text)

Comment: Obviously there is no need to examine the entire input unless the second letter `a` is all the way at the end. The most correct answers to this question will either use `[^aA]*` or `.*?` (note the question mark), as these are the clearest ways to prevent the engine from consuming the entire input. Wiktor is the victor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not go simple:

```
[aA].*[aA]
```

Additional pattern syntax like `[^aA]*` doesn't seem to add anything.

Comment: No, there is a **substantial performance difference** that will certainly become apparent on larger inputs. The greedy `*` tells the engine to try to match the longest stretch possible, which means that the matcher will walk all the way to the end of the string (since every character matches `.`) and then keep _backtracking_ until it finds the second `a` or `A` within things that already matched. For this case you could use `.*?`, but a good habit: [make adjacent tokens mutually exclusive](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast). Test inputs: "alpha" with 0 chars after it, versus 1M.

Comment: To clarify further: `[^aA]*` examines/matches the fewest characters and has zero backtracking. `.*?` examines/matches the fewest characters and has backtracking for every character between the first and second "a". `.*` examines all characters and has backtracking for every character after the last "a". To me, the best option is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

`pineapple` shouldn't match, should it?

I would suggest `([aA].*){2,}` because I think it's easier to read.

Here with unit tests based on your suggestions: https://regex101.com/r/WJnTW5/2

Comment: (1) This introduces a superfluous capture group (memory/time implications). To make a non-capturing group, use `(?:   )`. (2) Avoid greedy match-everything `.*` for a case like this: the algo that examines the least input is probably the best general algo. (3) You only care about matching two, not many. So with the corrections, you are left with `(?:[aA].*?){2}` which IMO is not prettier than [Wiktor's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61780109/regex-checks-a-letter-repeating-at-least-twice/71165928#comment109276642_61780109).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one very simple:

```
    (r"a.*a", text, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Another way is:

if you put [Aa]{n} it means you want A/a to be repeated for a consecutively n times which is not in this case as a is separated by characters for example in banana, a is separated by n... so we use [Aa].*[Aa]

```
    (r"[Aa].*[Aa]", text)
```

Both ways it works.

Answer (score 0):

i wrote this and it worked:

```
re.search(r"a[a-z ]*a", text, re.IGNORECASE)
```

so find the first a, go through any of these characters plus the " ", any number of times until you find another a, and this regardless of the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.search(r"[aA].*a", text)
```

Comment: This is more or less what was already suggested in the accepted answer, it doesn't really add anything. Also just providing code but no explanation makes it a poor quality answer. I'd recommend to delete.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -2):

This way will work:

```
(r"a+.+a", text.lower())
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Fails to match on "aa".